# Can I cancel the RxJs delay?

Tags: rxjs

I have a delay between some backend requests configured to 60 seconds using RxJs [delayWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delaywhen).
What I want to achieve is the possibility to cancel the ongoing delay at some point.

Let's say 30 seconds of delay passed and user is making some action. I want to trigger a backend request immediately, without waiting for the next 30 seconds to pass.

Is there a way to do this using rxJs?

Comment: I had one possible solution but it is kindy a hacky. I thought to configure a delay for 5 seconds and check if 12 of those delays were completed before making a backend call. (that gives 60 seconds in total)
This way, I can influence the delay (in 5 seconds granularity) by changing the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is theoretical and there might be better ways to do it, but the [takeUntil operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) might be helpful.

What could happen is that you could have a button on your page. The button, when clicked, could emit an event `buttonClicked$`. The operation that you want to trigger may listen to that event:

```
yourDesiredEvent$.pipe(
  takeUntil(buttonClicked$), 
  ...
)
```

And once your button is clicked (which would emit the `buttonClicked$` event), it could cancel listening to the 30 seconds rule and just trigger the backend call.

If any information here is faulty let me know, so I remove it in the hopes to not be misleading. :)